# LuaLaTeX: german special character ß with `newpxtext`

Tags: fonts, luatex, font-encodings

I use the font Palatino from the package [`newpxtext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx) in combination with LuaLaTeX. With this package it is not possible to set the german special character `ß` directly:

```
% Magic comments for TeXstudio
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
% Font: Palatino
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

Draußen währt am längsten.

Drau\ss en währt am längsten.

\end{document}
```

The result from the MWE is: `DrauSSen währt am längsten.`. It works when I switch to `fontspec`.

How is it possible to use the sign `ß` instead of `\ss` to set a text?

Comment: it makes no sense to use an Type 1 font and LuaTeX when there is a similar OpenType font like TeXGyre Pagella. See Ulrikes answer!

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this difference. Now I know why `fontspec` does not work well with `newpxtext` package.

Comment: use the Pagella font, then there is no need for newpx.

Comment: Please see [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28734)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the ß active and define it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\catcode`\ß=13
\defß{\ss}
\begin{document}

Draußen währt am längsten.

Drau\ss en währt am längsten.

\end{document}
```

That's more or less what luainputenc does. But it is much better to use fontspec instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} %palatino clone

\begin{document}
Draußen währt am längsten.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I modify my document with respect to your suggestions. What do you think, which sansserif-font fits best to Palatino? Helvetia (`tex-gyre-heros`), as in newpxtext?

Comment: And another question rises: Is it correct to use `\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}`? Or do I have to use `\setmathfont{}` instead? If yes, which font contains the euler font? Thanks!

Comment: @Dirk: Palatino Sans.

Comment: @Martin Wie lade ich Palatino Sans? Ein `\setsansfont{Palatino Sans}` gibt mir eine Fehlermeldung.

Comment: @Dirk: You have to _buy_ the font. :-)

Comment: @Martin Sorry for my german answer. I even thought so. ;-) However, which sans font fits good to Palatino? Currently I use `TeX Gyre Heros`.

Comment: @Dirk: You mean which _free_ sans is a good fit? [What is a good font for URLs to go with Palatino for the main text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2506)

Answer (score 11):

Which input encoding are you using? If you don't use fontspec, whatever the input encoding is you must indicate it to LuaLaTeX. E.g. if your editor is configured with utf8-unicode, you must insert the line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
```

in the preamble of your program. In that case your file works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for your hint to `luainputenc`. I always use utf8. However, I thougth one has to use utf8 with LuaLaTeX. That is the reason I did not mentioned it.

Comment: You only have to enter your code in utf8 if the fontspec package is loaded (which is recommanded). Otherwise you may use any encoding you wish, you only have to specify it to LuaLaTeX via the `luainputenc`package. That's the way to go if you want to import old 8-bits-encoded documents to LuaLaTeX.