# Errors with Umlauts in Glossary Label

Tags: glossaries

If I use umlauts in the glossary label, LaTeX does throw a lot of exceptions, one of them:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...lgröße}{name={},plural={},description={}}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Zielgröße}{name={},plural={},description={}}
```

*EDIT:* **How can I get the glossary to work with umlauts?**

Answer (score 3):

don't use Umlauts in the key:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Zielgroesse}{name={sample},plural={},description={}}

here is my \gls{Zielgroesse} exemplar
```

produces 'here is my sample exemplar'.

Comment: I know that this is working. That was not the question. The question was how i get it to work. I just found out the answer by my self. I will post it in a minute.

Comment: but your code shows you were using pdfTeX which does not recognise Umlauts as linguistic Umlauts. Hence, I provided you with a solution based upon the Information you gave. If by 'how I get it to work' meant how could one can actually use Umlauts in the glossary key then you have found a way.

Comment: Yes, that was what i tried to say. Sorry for the misunderstanding through my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how i can use umlauts in the glossarentry key.

First i learned that Latexmk, with witch i build the latex documents, just can't read something else than ASCI (no utf-8). The comand `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` just changes the umlauts into macros and that is where the error comes from in the glossaries package.

As solution i could use **XeTeX** or **LuaTeX**.

[Source (german)](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1193/missing-endcsname-inserted-bei-einem-label-was-ist-die-ursache)

I decided for LuaLaTeX but got some new errors and also had to change the following:

- delete `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- change `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to `\usepackage{fontspec}`
- change `\usepackage{lmodern}` to `\usepackage{mathpazo}`
- delete `\usepackage{pdfpages}`
- change Bibtex to Biber

[Source for the need of fontspec and a new font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158511/lualatex-german-special-character-%C3%9F-with-newpxtext)

Now, everything works great!